# App for collaborative shopping list (alternative to Out of Milk)

Tags: android, ios, collaboration

We are three user who want to cooperate regarding to the shopping list. 
We want to use an app that acts as a shopping list.

What app can you recommend us to use?

Criteria:

- We use Android and iOS (iPhone).
- The users should enable to add, delete and update the shopping list automatically (if possible).
- If possible, user retrieve the latest shopping list in real time.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be the perfect use case for [Bring!](https://www.getbring.com/#!/app).

They support muliple shopping lists, and a realtime sharing of the lists between a group of users. If someone goes shopping, the others can add some new items on the fly.

While in the shop, you can just tap the items to acknowledge the purchase, and remove the item from the "todo" list.

I use it personally (not in a group though), and it's very easy. It's free too. They support Android and iPhone.